# RS485 Communication

Tags: serial, rs485

I need resourceful information's on how to implement the serial protocol via an RS485 interface. As regards to my area of application, I simple want to communicate with my micro-controller via an RS485 port. How do I go about this? Any useful links with useful steps will be appreciated.

EDIT:

I am designing an energy meter with interfaces in-other for it to communicate with the outside world, to READ and WRITE informations. I intend to add to it the RS485 interface just like the Optical communication interface which I have already implemented. I want to know if there is anyway I can combine the serial protocol communicating via the RS485 interface. I hope this is more clearer.

Thanks

Comment: this is pretty broad, and will probably attract negative attention as written - you may want to edit your question before that happens.

Comment: i.e., what microcontroller? rs485 ports aren't common on PC hardware, so what have you got that has a 485 port? Or do you actually mean 232? You need to supply details in order to get answers.

Comment: There's a mild language barrier here. "THE serial protocol" is not meaningful, as there are probably tens of thousands of serial protocols in the world. I assume you have an existing protocol that you are using over an optical link, that you would like to use over RS485? RS485 probably has a much smaller bandwidth than optical, and it also is only half duplex. It is also a good idea to have a delay of at least 1-5ms between any transmitting and receiving to allow transmitters to power up and down. Can you force your optical protocol to work with those constraints?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I want to know if there is anyway I can combine the serial protocol communicating via the RS485 interface

RS485 doesn't have any defined serial protocol -- it's just the physical layer for specifying a multidrop differential signaling network, + a UART data link layer for encoding bytes via start/stop bits like RS232.

Answer (score 1):

Covert the sensor output by using controller to UART (Rx/Tx) standard. Feed the same UART signal into the input of RS485 electrical level converter and inject into your transmission medium.
i.e, transmission medium will carry UART-RS485 differential signal.

Answer (score 0):

RS485 is a hardware specification like RS232 but for noisy situation.

you need a rs485 tranceiver chip (convert uart signal to the rs485 differential signals).

Then just exchange data using the UART with a selected speed/start/stop bits...

RS485 does not have any communication protocol.
if you want to exchange raw bytes you don't need any communication protocol but if you think you need one you can either use MODBUS or imagine your own simple protocol.
e.g.

give a format to your frame and fix the size of your frame in order to decode it from the receiver side:

> Addr-Command-Data-CRC

**Addr** : Address of the device that you want to send to data to (since many device can be connected in the same line(bus) in the RS485 specifications)

**Command** : specify what type of data we are sending (e.g. read Temperature, Set Com Speed ....)

**Data**: e.g. temperature

**CRC** : check if the data is not corrupted after transmission (happen if many devices are in the same line try to communicate simultaneously, or if the line are too noisy too long ...)